# Is there a Microsoft Azure Ansible Module for Identity Management?

Tags: python, azure, ansible

Looking through the Azure provided [Ansible Modules](https://github.com/Azure/azure_modules), and [Collection](https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure), I see no obvious options to replicate the Azure CLI `az identity` command set.
Furthermore, because the Python modules used in the Ansible version of Azure are not compatible with the Azure CLI (at least on OSX), you cannot mix the use of Ansible modules for some things, and `command` or `shell` to fill the gaps as you normally would in Ansible.
Contributing my own upstream is, of course, an option, but I can't believe I'm the first to try and solve this

Answer (score 0):

So I have found an absolutely disgusting workaround that I should've thought of earlier.

- Install the Azure CLI outside of the virtualenv that will run Ansible, and ensure the `az` command is on your `PATH` variable, e.g using `curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash` and following the prompts, or `brew install` on OSX.

  - Install Ansible in a virtualenv using the typical `pip install ansible[azure]`
  - Mix and match to your heart's content, knowing this is a filthy solution you probably shouldn't use in AWX.